# Opposite of melt in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape, melt

I cannot figure out how to do "reverse melt" using Pandas in python.
This is my starting data

```
  label type  value
0     x    a      1
1     x    b      2
2     x    c      3
3     y    a      4
4     y    b      5
5     y    c      6
6     z    a      7
7     z    b      8
8     z    c      9
```

This is the output I would like to have:

```
label   a   b   c
    x   1   2   3
    y   4   5   6
    z   7   8   9
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: [Docstring of melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html): "Unpivots" a DataFrame... :)

Comment: I've provided several detailed examples and alternative approaches in this  [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336654)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html

Answer (score 138, accepted):

there are a few ways:

using [`.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
>>> origin.pivot(index='label', columns='type')['value']
type   a  b  c
label         
x      1  2  3
y      4  5  6
z      7  8  9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

using [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> origin.pivot_table(values='value', index='label', columns='type')
       value      
type       a  b  c
label             
x          1  2  3
y          4  5  6
z          7  8  9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

or [`.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [`.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
>>> origin.groupby(['label', 'type'])['value'].aggregate('mean').unstack()
type   a  b  c
label         
x      1  2  3
y      4  5  6
z      7  8  9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Great! I want to turn this into a simple dict now, with the index column also coming. How to do that?

Comment: which of the above is most general? If, instead of there being a single value column, there had been many - which would typically be used? (pivot?)

Comment: Nice to see there are different ways of doing this, but based on what should one decide which one to use?

Answer (score 8):

### [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df.set_index(['label','type'])['value'].unstack()

type   a  b  c
label         
x      1  2  3
y      4  5  6
z      7  8  9
```

**simplifying the passing of pivot arguments**

```
df.pivot(*df)

type   a  b  c
label         
x      1  2  3
y      4  5  6
z      7  8  9
```

---

```
[*df]
#['label', 'type', 'value']
```

---

**For expected output we need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)**

```
df.pivot(*df).rename_axis(columns = None).reset_index()

  label  a  b  c
0     x  1  2  3
1     y  4  5  6
2     z  7  8  9
```

---

### if there are duplicates in `a,b` columns we could lose information so we need [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
print(df)

  label type  value
0     x    a      1
1     x    b      2
2     x    c      3
3     y    a      4
4     y    b      5
5     y    c      6
6     z    a      7
7     z    b      8
8     z    c      9
0     x    a      1
1     x    b      2
2     x    c      3
3     y    a      4
4     y    b      5
5     y    c      6
6     z    a      7
7     z    b      8
8     z    c      9
```

---

```
df.pivot_table(index = ['label',
                        df.groupby(['label','type']).cumcount()],
               columns = 'type',
               values = 'value')


type     a  b  c
label           
x     0  1  2  3
      1  1  2  3
y     0  4  5  6
      1  4  5  6
z     0  7  8  9
      1  7  8  9
```

---

Or:

```
(df.assign(type_2 = df.groupby(['label','type']).cumcount())
   .set_index(['label','type','type_2'])['value']
   .unstack('type'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (
df.pivot(index="label",columns="type",values="value").
reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
)
```

Another method:

```
df.groupby(["label","type"])["value"].sum().unstack()
```

Another:

pd.crosstab(index=df.label,columns=df.type,values=df.value,aggfunc="su

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply