# Rearranging Data in Python/Pandas: Turn specific column vlaues into headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have been given a large dataset that has data arranged like so:

```
location  cost    year
1         23.15    1986
1         23.91    1988
1         23.31    1989
1         23.91    1993
1         22.98    1994
1         23.99    1995
1         23.71    1997
1         23.01    1999
2         23.21    2000
2         24.28    2004
2         24.4     2005
```

I'd like to rearrange this so it is in the form:

```
location    1985    1986    1987   1988
1           20.00   20.00   20.0    20.0
2           20.00   20.00   20.0    20.0
3           20.00   20.00   20.0    20.0
4           20.00   20.00   20.0    20.0
5           20.00   20.00   20.0    20.0
```

(note: ignore that the new costs are all 20.0. My goal is to turn the values within the `year` column into headers, so that each `location` is only listed once, with the `cost` for a specific year located in that column.)

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I've looked into `groupy` and `transpose` but have not been able to produce anything close to what I'd like.

Thank you in advance for any pointers you can provide.

Comment: Why are all the columns `20.0[0]`?

Comment: Just for the sake of example position; the values aren't real.

Comment: It's a little confusing. Might be worth showing real values you'd expect.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127569/opposite-of-melt-in-python-pandas

Comment: It might also be good to see your current code.

Comment: I've clarified the example to better indicate the values are not real. If I could get the data in the form that I'd like with real values, I wouldn't be stuck on this problem.

Comment: Just to add to @erip's comment, if you used "real" data, we'd be able to see how you expect to handle null/mising/multiple values for a cell (doesn't have to be real data, but data that matches your example list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='location', columns='year', values='cost', fill_value=0)
```

With your sample:

```
#Out[11]: 
#year       1986   1988   1989   1993   1994   1995   1997   1999   2000  \
#location                                                                  
#1         23.15  23.91  23.31  23.91  22.98  23.99  23.71  23.01   0.00   
#2          0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  23.21   

#year       2004  2005  
#location               
#1          0.00   0.0  
#2         24.28  24.4
```