# Splitting pandas series into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm extracting large amounts of entries from a database (> 15 millions entries) with the goal of exporting to a CSV file. What I get at the end of my request is a one-column dataframe with over 15 millions rows. I'm looking for a function to split the entries into multiple columns every million entries.

So for a 5 million entries column, I would like to have 5 columns of 1 million entries each.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can `reshape` the df values: `pd.DataFame(df.values.reshape(1000000,5))`

Comment: This might be an interesting answer for your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22127685/2849552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @EdChum that this would be simplest given a Series object named `s`:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape(1000000, -1))
```

which would reshape your Series into a DataFrame of shape `(1,000,000, s.len / 1,000,000)`.

---

However, the above only works if you have a series whose length is an exact multiple of 1,000,000.  Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
    # note with python3, you need to use integer division // here
    s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x/1000000,x%1000000) for x in s.index])
    # or an alternative below which does the same thing
    #s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.index.map(lambda x: (x/1000000, x%1000000)))
    s.unstack(0)
```

which will give you several columns of the same length with the last column padded with `NaN`s.

Here's an example with a Series of length 55 which I want split into columns of length 10.  Note the last column has the last 5 values set to `NaN`:

```
In [42]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(55))

In [43]: s
Out[43]: 
0      0
1      1
2      2
...
53    53
54    54
dtype: int64

#                                                      with python3 x//10, x%10
In [44]: s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.index.map(lambda x: (x/10, x%10)))

In [45]: s.unstack(0)
Out[45]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5
0  0  10  20  30  40  50
1  1  11  21  31  41  51
2  2  12  22  32  42  52
3  3  13  23  33  43  53
4  4  14  24  34  44  54
5  5  15  25  35  45 NaN
6  6  16  26  36  46 NaN
7  7  17  27  37  47 NaN
8  8  18  28  38  48 NaN
9  9  19  29  39  49 NaN
```

Note two things:

1. that using `s.index.map(lambda ...)` should be faster than the list comprehension for very large arrays.
2. if using python3, make sure to user integer division in the lambda function:  `lambda x: (x // N, x % N)`.

Comment: I tested it and I do not get the same output as mentioned. Instead of having 1,2,3, etc. I have 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 for the columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which method did you test?  Does your series index start at 0 and increase to len(series)-1?

Comment: I used both methods you mentionned with the very example used above

Comment: @John_Mtl, are you using python3?  If so, see the small edit above; you need to use integer division `//` in the lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your time, it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

And the ugliest line of code award goes to....

```
x = 1000000
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.array(df[df.columns[0]].tolist())[:-(len(df)%x )].reshape(len(df)//x, x)), pd.DataFrame(df[df.columns[0]].tolist()[len(df) - len(df)%x:])] , axis=1)
```

You should be set for any value of x. No doubt stuff can be 100% prettier, was just messing around with ipython ;)

Comment: I get a memory error from Python trying this one. Guess it is eating too much!