# python groupby: how to move hierarchical grouped data from columns into rows?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

i’ve got a python/pandas groupby that is grouped on name and looks like this:

```
name    gender      year        city            city total
jane    female      2011        Detroit          1
                    2015        Chicago          1
dan     male        2009        Lexington        1  
bill    male        2001        New York         1
                    2003        Buffalo          1
                    2000        San Francisco    1
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
 name   gender  year1   city1     year2 city2    year3  city3   city total
 jane   female  2011    Detroit   2015  Chicago                  2
 dan    male    2009    Lexington                                1  
 bill   male    2000    Chico     2001  NewYork  2003   Buffalo  3
```

so i want to keep the grouping by name and then order by year and make each name have only one column. it's a variation on a dummy variables maybe? i'm not even sure how to summarize it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127569/opposite-of-melt-in-python-pandas

Comment: i still can't figure it out. when i pivot it i get the list of cities and years for each name but then how do i move the first entry of the list to "year 1" and etc?