# Finding an efficient way to reshape a dataframe: from n*m to 1*(n+m)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm finding an efficient to reshape a N*M dataframe to 1*(N*M) dataframe:

INPUT>

`df1`

```
ID   distUnit col_a   col_b
1000   150      35     55
1000   250      10     20
1200   150      12     13
1200   250      16     20
```

DESIRED OUTPUT>

```
ID   col_a_150   col_b_150  col_a_250 col_b_250
1000   35            55        10          20
1200   12            13        16          20
```

**My idea>**

1. Go through every row in df1
2. add prefix to *col_a* and *col_b* based on the value of `row['distUnit']`
3. using `combined_first` to add processed row back to result dataframe

**Challenging part >**

Since the size of my input data is 14440 * 20, my idea is not efficient enough.

Wondering any better implementation ways to solve this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Split this into two DFs according to `distUnit`, then merge the two keyed by ID.  That should give you a one-line operation, rather than iterating over the data frame.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Should avoid iterating and keep separation idea in the mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pair (ID, distUnit) is unique across your dataset, you can simply "unmelt" your dataframe like this:

```
df=df.groupby(['ID','distUnit'])['col_a','col_b'].mean().unstack()
df.columns =  [f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' for col in df.columns.values]
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127569/opposite-of-melt-in-python-pandas) question for similar approaches.

Comment: Thanks. This method made me be more familiar with pandas Group by.