# Dataframe - convert rows to columns - grouped by another columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to convert a data frame as below

Original dataset

| Group | Miles |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| A | 20 |
| A | 24 |
| A | 25 |
| B | 12 |
| B | 17 |
| B | 16 |
| B | 19 |

I want to convert from above format to this :

| Col_A | Col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 12 |
| 20 | 17 |
| 24 | 16 |
| 25 | 19 |

Comment: welcome to SO, I recommend that you check [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should start with explaining what you've tried first etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127569/opposite-of-melt-in-python-pandas will give you some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TRY via `pivot`:

```
df = df.assign(t= df.groupby('Group').cumcount()).pivot(index = 't', columns ='Group', values = 'Miles').add_prefix('Col_').rename_axis(columns = None).reset_index(drop = True)
```

##### OR via `pd.concat`:

```
k = pd.concat([g.reset_index(drop=True)['Miles'] for _,g in df.groupby('Group')], 1)
k.columns = ['colA', 'colB']
```

##### One more option via `set_index`/`unstack`:

```
k = df.set_index(['Group', df.groupby('Group').cumcount()]).unstack(0).add_prefix('Col_').rename_axis(columns= [None,None])
k.columns = k.columns.droplevel()
```

##### One more via `groupby` / `explode`:

```
k = df.groupby('Group').agg(list).T.apply(pd.Series.explode).add_prefix('Col_')
k = k.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns = None)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0     23     12
1     20     17
2     24     16
3     25     19
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) option:

```
df = (
    df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('Group').cumcount(),
                   columns='Group',
                   values='Miles')
        .add_prefix('Col_')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

`df`:

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0     23     12
1     20     17
2     24     16
3     25     19
```

---

Explaination:

Create a new index based on the relative position in each group with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount):

```
df.groupby('Group').cumcount()
```

```
Group  new_index
    A          0
    A          1
    A          2
    A          3
    B          0
    B          1
    B          2
    B          3
```

Then `Group` can become the new columns in the wide format Frame.

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('Group').cumcount(),
                   columns='Group',
                   values='Miles')
```

```
Group   A   B
0      23  12
1      20  17
2      24  16
3      25  19
```

Then some cleanup with [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html#pandas-dataframe-add-prefix) + [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-rename-axis):

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('Group').cumcount(),
               columns='Group',
               values='Miles')
    .add_prefix('Col_')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
```

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0     23     12
1     20     17
2     24     16
3     25     19
```

Comment: I always miss the fact that we can pass series directly!! :P