# How to check if string elements of lists are in dataframe/other list (python)

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops

I got the following problem. I do have 2 lists/dataframes. One is a list/dataframe of customers, where every row is a customer, the columns are synonyms for these customers, other verbal expressions.

```
customer_list = {'A': ['AA', 'AA', 'AAA'], 'B': ['B', 'BB','BBB'], 'C': ['C','CC','CCC']}
customer_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(customer_list, orient='index')
```

Than I have another dataframe with the following structure:

```
text = [['A', 'Hello i am AA', 'Hello i am BB', 'Hello i am A'], ['B', 'Hello i am B', 'Hello i am BBB','Hello i am BB'], ['C', 'Hello i am AAA','Hello i am CC','Hello i am CCC']]
text_df = pd.DataFrame(text)
text_df = text_df.set_index(0)
text_df = text_df.rename_axis("customer")
```

How (which types, which functions) can I check every row (e.g. every element of row "A") of the text_df for "wrong entries", which means for all the elements/synonyms of other customers (so check for every entry besides the own). Do I have to create multiple dataframes in a for loop? Is one loop enough?

Thanks for any advice, even just a hint concerning methods.
For my example, a result like

*Wrong texts: A: Hello i am BB,
C: Hello i am AAA* or some according indices would be great.

[image: data1]
[image: data2]

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want a dataframe with only the correct values or do you want a list with all the incorrect values?

Comment: A list with the incorrect values and maybe their position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would `pd.melt` to transform this `DataFrame` into an "index" of `(customer, column, value)` triples, like so:

```py
df = pd.melt(text_df.reset_index(), id_vars="customer", var_name="columns")
```

Now, we have a way of "efficiently" operating over the entire data without needing to figure out the "right" columns and the like. So let's solve the "correctness" problem.

```py
def correctness(melted_row: pd.Series, customer_df: pd.DataFrame) -> bool:
    customer = customer_df.loc[melted_row.customer]
    cust_ids = customer.values.tolist()
    return any([melted_row.value.endswith(cust_id) for cust_id in cust_ids])
```

**Note:** You could swap out `.endswith` with a variety of `str` functions to match your needs. Take a look at the docs, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#method-summary).

Lastly, you can generate a mask by using the `apply` method across rows, like so:

```py
df["correct"] = df.apply(correctness, axis=1, args=(customer_df, ))
```

You'll then have an output that looks like this:

```py
  customer columns           value  correct
0        A       1   Hello i am AA     True
1        B       1    Hello i am B     True
2        C       1  Hello i am AAA    False
3        A       2   Hello i am BB    False
4        B       2  Hello i am BBB     True
5        C       2   Hello i am CC     True
6        A       3    Hello i am A    False
7        B       3   Hello i am BB     True
8        C       3  Hello i am CCC     True
```

I imagine you have other things you want to do before "un-melting" you data, so [I'll point you to this SO question on how to "un-melt" your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127569/opposite-of-melt-in-python-pandas).

---

By "efficient", I really mean that you have a way of leveraging built-in functions of `pandas`, not that it's "computationally efficient". My memory is foggy on this, but using `.apply(...)` is generally something to do as a last-resort. I imagine there are multiple ways to crack this problem that use built-ins, but I find this solution to be the most readable.

Comment: For row 6, `Hello i am A`, should that be `True`?

Comment: Good catch! I just checked -- this solution will work, but I used the data they gave in the question which lists the aliases of `A` as `['AA', 'AA', 'AAA']`, so based on that, `Hello i am A` _should_ evaluate to `False`, as it does. :)

Comment: You're right @John. I missed that in the `customer_df`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that worked perfectly fine. Thanks also for the explanations and notes, this is way i definitely would not have come up with, the more valuable it is for me.