# How to create new columns in python for loop using variable column names?

Tags: python, dataframe

For some background, I've been trying to take the average of a dataset for each fiscal week for each unique name in the dataset as well. I start with the dataset that looks something like this:

| pad | fiscal_week | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Verace | 5 | 23 |
| Jersey | 5 | 20 |
| Verace | 5 | 20 |
| Verace | 5 | 22 |
| Verace | 6 | 30 |
| Colorado | 4 | 15 |

What I currently have:

```
    unique_week = df['fiscal_week'].unique()
    unique_week = sorted(unique_week)
    newCols = pd.DataFrame()

    for week_number in unique_week:
        unique_id = df['pad'].unique()
        turbine_reg = df[df['fiscal_week'] == week_number]
        newColname = 'FW' + str(week_number)

        for turbine_name in unique_id:
            turbine_name_reg = turbine_reg[turbine_reg['pad'] == turbine_name]
            value_mean = [turbine_name_reg['value'].mean()]

            newCols['Turbine'] = turbine_name
            newCols[newColname] = direct_mean
```

What I would like, is for the end product to look something like:

| pad | FW1 | FW2 | FW3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Verace | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| Jersey | 15 | 16 | 20 |
| Colorado | 23 | 25 | 16 |

Currently, I'm only getting the result for the last unique pad the loop run on and not saving the times it runs for the other pads. I know the loop is overwriting itself each time, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you actually want to use `df.groupby` to *group* the dataframe *by* the `pad` and `fiscal_week` columns.

For example, starting with this dataframe `df`:

```
         pad  fiscal_week  value
0    Verace             5     23
1    Jersey             5     20
2    Verace             5     20
3    Verace             5     22
4    Verace             6     30
5  Colorado             4     15
```

We can compute the pad-wise, fiscal week-wise mean with:

```
df.groupby(['pad', 'fiscal_week']).mean()
```

output:

```
                           value
pad       fiscal_week           
Colorado  4            15.000000
Jersey    5            20.000000
Verace    5            21.666667
          6            30.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pivot table is what you are looking for:

```
        pad  fiscal_week  value
0    Verace            5     23
1    Jersey            5     20
2    Verace            5     20
3    Verace            5     22
4    Verace            6     30
5  Colorado            4     15
```

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['pad'], columns=['fiscal_week'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

```
fiscal_week     4          5     6
pad
Colorado     15.0        NaN   NaN
Jersey        NaN  20.000000   NaN
Verace        NaN  21.666667  30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use groupby() function for get every pad's mean in fiscal weeks.

```
data.groupby(by = ["pad", "fiscal_week"])["value"].aggregate('mean')
```

This code spinnet will returns a table like this:

| pad | fiscal_week | meanValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Colorade | 4 | 15 |
| Jersey | 5 | 20 |
| Verace | 5 | 21 |
| Verace | 6 | 30 |

Then you need to add unstack() function to get fiscal_weeks as columns. You can check this answer to get more detailed information about [unstack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60215826/12569333)

```
data.groupby(by = ["pad", "fiscal_week"])["value"].aggregate('mean').unstack()
```

Finally you will get a table like this:

| fiscal_week | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Colorade | x | x | x |
| Jersey | x | x | x |
| Verace | x | x | x |

I think this is the format which you want. After these processes you can use functions to edit your table. (E.g rename, reset_index, drop)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for and way more simpler than what I was trying to do! Thank you so much!